# Entity Framework Core - where clause on encrypted column

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

It is not possible for Entity Framework Core to generate a query to check an encrypted column for null values?

For example:

```
context.mytable.Where(x.myencryptedcolumn != null).Select(x => x.ID)
```

generates the following statement

```
SELECT [t].[ID]
FROM [mytable] AS [t]
```

Are there any workarounds for this?

Comment: Is that the literal code pasted from your app? Is it free of typos?

Comment: @CaiusJard yes it is as posted

Comment: So, if *`.Where(x.myencryptedcolumn != null)`* is not a typo, where does the `x` in the Where clause come from? Why does it not give you a "cannot convert from bool to Func<T, bool>" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can encrypt the query param on client side like you are encrypting while inserting.

```
context.mytable.Where(x.myencryptedcolumn != null).Select(x => encrypt(x.ID))
```

But for this to work, you will need to keep the `IV` of `signing key` fixed. This will make sure that it always produces same encrypted value.
However this weakens security.

Comment: The encryption is done at the Db so I cant do this.